# Can we send data from Google cloud storage to SFTP server using GCP Cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, sftp, pysftp

I want to take a .csv file from Google cloud storage and send it to SFTP server. I do not know, what I am doing wrong, but I am getting the error that *file not found* in the cloud storage. My code is below:

```
import base64
import os
import pysftp
import re
import csv
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

def hello_sftp(event, context):
    
    #defining credentials for the transfer
    myHostName = 'lmno.abcd.com'
    myUsername = 'pqr'
    myPassword = 'xyz'
    filename = 'test_file.csv'
    path = "gs://testing/"

    copy_file_on_ftp(myHostName, myUsername, myPassword, filename, path)
   
def copy_file_on_ftp(myHostName, myUsername, myPassword, filename, localpath):
    
    remotepath = '/Export/' + str(filename)
    print(' ')
    print(localpath)
    print(' ')
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    
    with pysftp.Connection(
    host=myHostName, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts
    ) as sftp:
        print("Connection successfully established . . . ")
        print("Exporting . . . ")
        print("local path and file name is : ", localpath+filename)
        sftp.put(localpath =localpath+filename, remotepath=remotepath)
    sftp.close()
    print("export to sFTP successful!")
```

but I get the error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://testing/test_file.csv'

Is it not possible to send the data there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pysftp does not understand `gs://`.

Instead, use Google API to download the file to SFTP file-like object representing the target file on the SFTP server opened with the pysftp:

```py
storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
with sftp.open(remotepath, 'w', 32768) as f:
    blob.download_to_file(f)
```