# Truncating the file while saving on SFTP server using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, sftp, pysftp

This is extended question to [Can we send data from Google cloud storage to SFTP server using GCP Cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772938/can-we-send-data-from-cloud-storage-to-sftp-server-using-gcp-cloud-function)

```py
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostName, username=myUsername, 
                      password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(filename) #source_blob_name
    with sftp.open(remotepath, 'w+', 32768) as f:
        blob.download_to_file(f)
```

The `W+`/`w` command is not truncating the previous file and throwing error. This is when there is already a file with same name in SFTP server existing! what should be the optimal solution to this?

The complete error code log is

```
gcs-to-sftp
4wz44jq3oe2g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 728, in download_blob_to_file
    checksum=checksum,
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 986, in _do_download
    response = download.consume(transport, timeout=timeout)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/download.py", line 168, in consume
    self._process_response(result)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_download.py", line 186, in _process_response
    response, _ACCEPTABLE_STATUS_CODES, self._get_status_code
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 104, in require_status_code
    *status_codes
google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 449, in run_background_function
    _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 268, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 265, in call_user_function
    event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context))
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 20, in hello_sftp
    copy_file_on_ftp(myHostName, myUsername, myPassword, bucket_name, filename)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 42, in copy_file_on_ftp
    file_to_export.download_to_file(f)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1128, in download_to_file
    checksum=checksum,
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 731, in download_blob_to_file
    _raise_from_invalid_response(exc)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 4100, in _raise_from_invalid_response
    raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/sftp__test/o/test_file.csv?alt=media: No such object: sftp__test/test_file.csv: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` in `w+` mode should not be there. It opens the file for both reading and writing, what is not needed in your scenario.

Although the `w` should truncate the file (and it does on the common OpenSSH Linux server), it does not seem to work with your server, when combined with the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on what @Martin-Prikryl suggested

replace

```
with sftp.open(remotepath, 'w+', 32768) as f:
```

with

```
sftp.open(remotepath, "wb")
```

---

or use

```
from io import BytesIO

flo = BytesIO() 
blob.download_to_file(flo) 
flo.seek(0) 
sftp.putfo(flo,remotepath)
```